# Getting “Authentication failed. System.InvalidOperationException” error intermittently with jquery call to Webmethod

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, forms-authentication, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebMethod in ASP.NET Webform, sitting in code behind of a foo.aspx page

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static String foo()
    {
       return "";
    }
```

I invoke it using jQuery

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("foo.aspx/foo")%>',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataToServer),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data ) {
                 // work with data here
            }
        });
```

And this is the response header from the server

```
Request   
Request Method:POST
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
2:2
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:105
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 20 Jan 2015 04:40:36 GMT
jsonerror:true
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

response body

```
{"Message":"Authentication failed.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

Background information

- I do not use ASP.NET Friendly URL so please don't suggest me to turn
  AutoRedirectMode = Off.
- I do use WebApi in my site, not sure if
  this's related. Here's my routing configuration

  ```
      RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "DefaultApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}"
      );


      RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "DefaultApiNoParameter",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
      );
  ```
- The site that I build is hosted as a sub-application within another
  ASP.NET application.  So let's call my application bar, it's hosted within foobar, on a domain foo.com so http://foo.com/foobar/bar. Sometimes, after a number of refreshes, the browser pop up "The site http://foo.com:80 needs you to key in password blah blah..". All sites have Anonymous Authentication Enabled and Forms Authentication Enabled, other Authenticaion are Disabled.
- This is my web.config authentication setting, the idea is that the
  application is public, only foo.aspx is private and password
  protected.

  ```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="cookie" loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="foo.aspx">
    <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1">
      <user name="foo"
            password="xxxxxxxx"/>
      <user name="bar"
            password="xxxxxxxxx"/>
    </credentials>
    </forms>
  </authentication>
  ```
- The application works just fine in the testing environment with a
  single web server. Only when deployed to a web farm then this problem
  happens.
- The error happens intermittently, sometimes a request work, sometimes it doesn't. After a few times of refreshing the page, I will be automatically logged out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The application works just fine in the testing environment with a single web server. Only when deployed to a web farm then this problem happens.

This typically happens when the encryption/decryption keys don't match across all instances

If you are using `SHA1` to hash the password you will need to make sure that all instances of the website share the same `machineKey` so that the hashing algorithm can hash the password correctly.

You can achieve that by adding the respective keys to the `web.config` file, for example...

```
<machineKey decryption="AES" 
            validation="SHA1" 
            decryptionKey="22B83C3D43B0BA0E2" 
            validationKey="1C059088E7E510C83650449D8D6567B2" />
```

as quoted in the MSDN documentation of the `machineKey` element related to the `...key` values...

> Specifies a manually assigned key. This value must be manually set to
>   a string of hexadecimal characters to ensure consistent configuration
>   across a Web farm. The key should be 16 hexadecimal characters in
>   length when using DES encryption and 48 hexadecimal characters in
>   length when using Triple DES (3DES) or AES encryption. If keys shorter
>   than the maximum length are used, the keys should be created by a
>   truly random means, such as by using the RNGCryptoServiceProvider
>   class. ASP.NET can use Triple DES only on computers on which 128-bit
>   encryption is available.

For info can be found in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: so I won't need to maintain the machineKey if I use Clear password right?

Comment: @Quannt no, you won't if you configure it to plain text, but only for this functionality. It is always a good practice to specify the machineKey element when deploying to a web farm and load-balanced infrastructure because there are other features in ASP.NET that will need to do basic cryptographic and encryption operations for example, viewstate is encrypted using an encryption key